# Place Element on Top Left Corner of Page

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I'm using materialize css in my web application and I'm trying to make use of the Click Only Fab. The problem is that this always ends up on the bottom right corner of my page, when I want it on the top left.

```
<div class="fixed-action-btn horizontal click-to-toggle" id="menuBtn">
      <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
          <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
      </a>
      <ul>
          <li><a class="btn-floating red"><i class="material-icons">insert_chart</i></a></li>
          <li><a class="btn-floating yellow darken-1"><i class="material-icons">format_quote</i></a></li>
          <li><a class="btn-floating green"><i class="material-icons">publish</i></a></li>
          <li><a class="btn-floating blue"><i class="material-icons">attach_file</i></a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

I tried everything including floating and aligning and nothing has worked. How can I get this on the top left corner of my page? So I can use it as a menu button.

Comment: which element you want to place in the top left corner.Can you please create a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you make a custom css class with

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
```

? Alternatively `fixed` instead of `absolute` if you want it in the corner of the display, not page. I would comment but bloody 50 rep required, will delete this answer if it turns out to be very wrong.

Comment: That actualy put it on the top right! How can I get in on the left?

Comment: @unconditionalcoder Just replace `right` by `left`.

Comment: @unconditionalcoder I recommend learning about [position](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) in CSS, it's incredibly useful. The `position` property defines how should an element be displayed and `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` are used to tell where exactly.